# How to get more context information before the target word when using elastic search highlight?

Tags: elasticsearch

Example text:

```
First sentense. Second sentense. The sentense contain target. Forth sentense.
```

When I search the "target" using highlight, elastic search returns

```
The sentense contain target. Forth sentense.
```

while I expect

```
 Second sentense. The sentense contain target. Forth sentense
```

My query:

```
GET chapter_document/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "content": "target"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "bookId"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "bookId": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "search_after" : ["10000097"],
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "content" : { 
        "pre_tags" : ["<hl>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</hl>"]
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I have tried:

According to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html), I tried to use greater fragment_size but ES returns more word after
**Forth sentense** thought I expect the words before **target**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is using postings highlighter which ignores `fragment_size`. You might get much better control by switching to `plain` or fast vector (`fvh`) highlighters. In this case you could specify the fragment size, boundary characters, and all other settings to improve highlighting experience.

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
         "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc?refresh
{
  "bookId": 10000096,
  "content": "First sentense. Second sentense. The sentense contain target. Forth sentence."
}


GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "content": "target"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "bookId"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "bookId": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "search_after" : ["10000097"],
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "content" : { 
        "pre_tags" : ["<hl>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</hl>"]
      }
    },
    "boundary_chars": "\n",
    "boundary_max_scan": 100,
    "type" : "fvh"
  }
}
```